# How to set DeviceIoControl (IOCTL)?

Tags: serial-port, ioctl

Have anyone experience using  "DeviceIoControl", this functions seems to be a way an application can do IO control (IOCTL) which is generally set for Driver for example:

```
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_LINE_CONTROL       
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_CHAR
```

I have a software communicating with modem, when I monitored with portmon(serial port monitoring tool), I saw that software is setting the above three parameter, I am writing that software of my own in c++, but I couldn't found any thing from where i can start. If any one having experience using this, please help me, if needed, i can brief more about this project.

Comment: These IOCTLs are used by documented winapi functions.  Which is what you should always use.  Use SetCommState() instead.

Comment: But i could not figure out how to set these two. this is the portmon output for the software i am using, but how can i set these IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_QUEUE_SIZE VSerial7_0 SUCCESS InSize: 16384 OutSize: 16384 and IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_TIMEOUTS VSerial7_0 SUCCESS RI:-1 RM:0 RC:0 WM:0 WC:65000, these two are not inside setcommstate()

Comment: Here is the MSDN link for above http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: SetupComm() and SetCommTimeouts().  Use [the fish](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).